# Unable to segregate response date in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am new to JMeter, so need some assistance.
I am working on an authentication flow.

Clarification:
Step 1: Authenticate number: Request- Mobile number, Response- OTP

Step 2: Verify number: Request- OTP, Response- Token & id(which comes in Response header)

Step 3: Token authentication: Request- Token & id, Response- Token(refresh-token) & ID
In Step 3, I get response as:
{"mobile":"+916666777711","token":"x6nUPk3NzveJ3mbF","customerId":"11030","appId":"com.senfina.shoppingjoe"}

I want to parse these data separately into another request. I have tried using Regular expression which didn't worked out. Is there any way to do this with BeanShell PostProcessor?
Let me know other options also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What regular expression configuration did you use? For particular your response it shouldn't be a problem to get token with something like `"token":"(\w+)"`

[image: Regular Expression extractor]

The best option to parse JSON data is using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) plugin with easy JSON Path expression of `$.token`. See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to **Parsing JSON**) for plugin installation and usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression extractor should work fine. Can you please post the expression that you are using. Also, I urge you to use [this](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) plugin as well.

Comment: Hi Naveen, Thanks for you reply. 

I am using **"token":"(.+?)"** to fetch token and using **${token}** in the header to feed it to another request.
I am getting error as "Not Found" (text which I have entered in Default value in Regular Expression Extractor)

Comment: Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: Extend the left boundary and right boundary to ","token":"(.+?)"," and try.